# How to show all albums in Wordpress NextGen Gallery

Tags: wordpress, cms

I have a Wordpress install setup as a simple CMS.  I am starting to use the NextGen Gallery plugin to support photo pages.  I expect to have a number of people uploading pictures, and not all of them are going to be technical enough to edit a page and insert the right tags to show new albums.

I have spent some time looking in the obvious places (other than the php source code), but I haven't found a way to make a page that shows **all** the albums that have been uploaded to the system.  I am sure this has to be an easy thing to do, so maybe I'm just not thinking the right way.  Any help is much appreciated.

Clarification:  I know that I can use the gallery tag and put in all the IDs for gallerys in the system now, but I want the page to automatically update to show any new gallerys added to the system at a later date.

Comment: If you have no luck here try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As @mawtex noted, this question is better for the Wordpress site.